# Transaction Scope inserting duplicate values. How to lock select query

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, transactionscope

i am using transaction scope in my project. Isolation level is IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted 
i Also tried IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead

```
using (DBOperations dboperation = new DBOperations())
{
  GetAccountVoucherNuber();
}
```

i am calling this method from Transaction Scope.

```
private void GetAccountVoucherNuber() {

    var _dB0010013 = _dB0010013Repository.GetAll().Where(e = > e.Category == "D" && e.CategoryType == "TSNO" && e.Branch == Branch && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(e.OnDate) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(TranInit.EntryDate) && e.CodeOne == BatchCode).FirstOrDefault();
    if (_dB0010013 == null) {
        _dB0010013 = new DB0010013();
        _dB0010013.Branch = Branch;
        _dB0010013.Category = "D";
        _dB0010013.CategoryType = "TSNO";
        _dB0010013.CodeOne = BatchCode;
        _dB0010013.CodeTwo = "";
        _dB0010013.CodeThree = "";
        _dB0010013.OnDate = TranInit.EntryDate;
        _dB0010013.Note = "";
        _dB0010013.LastNo = 1;

        var _operationStatus = _dB0010013Repository.AddAndSave(_dB0010013, false);
    } else {
        _dB0010013.LastNo += 1;
        var _operationStatus = _dB0010013Repository.UpdateAndSave(_dB0010013, false);
    }

}
```

when two or more user submits the page at same time.
 i am getting same no for two transaction.

eg. suppose user1 got lastNo =85 +=1 =86 

 at the same time user2 also get lastNo  =85 +=1 =86 

 so the same no is applied for two different transactions.

How Can i Lock Select Statement after getting values. or what is way to handle it.
i googled a lot but didnt find any solution.

My DbOperataion Class added for reference.

```
public class DBOperations:IDisposable
    {
        private TransactionScope transactionscope;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.transactionscope != null)
                this.transactionscope.Dispose();
        }
        public DBOperations()
        {
            this.Initialize();
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                this.Dispose();

                TransactionOptions transactionoption = new TransactionOptions();
                transactionoption.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
               transactionoption.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;

                this.transactionscope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionoption);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Data Error " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you use transaction scope ? The above codes have no codes about it.

Comment: when i create object of - DBOperations dboperation = new DBOperations() .  in construtor of this class i define transaction scope.

Comment: @Toro i have updated my quesion with dboperation class

Comment: When you call `Complete()` on your TransactionScope ? and `this.Dispose()` is strange . It seems the class will be disposed when it do ctor.

Comment: Hi @dvirus, how is it going?

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation, I usually make an extra table `AccountVoucherNumberGenerator` that hold the last number. Either you can do an insert and use Identity Insert (the easiest way) or you can choose to have just 1 row and update that row with the last used number.

Comment: but what is the use of creating extra table. i am using same logic with my dB0010013 table.

Comment: if you have two users at the same time they make 1 insert each in the new table and get diffrent numbers.

Comment: No I mean you insert a new row for each call, and let SQL Server do the +1 of lastNo instead of doing it in c#.

Comment: Can u elaborate in Code ex.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to set up `Transaction` by `TransactionOptions` and `TransactionScope` classes. From [Isolation Level on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)), the `RepeatableRead` level should be enough in your case.

```
using System.Transactions;
....

TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead;
// Set timeout to avoid dead lock conditions.
options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); 

using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options)) {

    // Execute this operation in the transaction.
    GetAccountVoucherNuber();

    // Call `Complete()` explicitly about transaction commit. Or, it will do rollback..... 
    trans.Complete();
}
```

I suppose to you SHOULD call `Complete()` on your `TransactionScope` .

### UPDATE

`Read uncommitted` will [do `read-lock` and `write-lock` in the transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(database)). In other words, your question is about to avoid `Non-repeatable reads`, and the `Read uncommitted` or `Serializable` isolation level could avoid the problem. If you need to avoid `Phantoms` problem, then you need to use `Serializable` isolation level. Different isolation level will have different lock behaviors.  About database locks, I am prefer [this book, database management systems.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072465638)

After transaction commit or rollback, it will release all resources it holds, including `read-locks` and `write-locks`.

Comment: Can we lock select query after read by user1? and unlock after committ

Comment: I update my answers. The transaction will do those locks for you.

Comment: RepeatableRead does not lock select query.

Comment: By your codes, the `DBOperations` doesn't call `Complete()` to commit the transaction. When the update or insert operations completes, the transaction does nothing.

Comment: i did commit after transaction complete above is just an example.

Comment: Maybe you need to modify your example ..... [The database has implemented 2-PL lock (read & write lock).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking)

Comment: I have an idea. If you change to `Serializable` level, does the question remains ? Or the `Serializable` level help nothing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72219/discussion-between-toro-and-dvirus).